# What is the maximum value of a pointer on Mac OSX?

Tags: c, macos, pointers

I'd like to make a custom pointer address printer (like the `printf(%p)`) and I'd like to know what is the maximum value that a pointer can have on the computer I'm using, which is an iMac OS X 10.8.5.

Someone recommended I use an `unsigned long`. Is the following cast the adapted one and big enough ?

```
function print_address(void *pointer)
{
    unsigned long a;
    a = (unsigned long) pointer;
    [...]
}
```

I searched in the `limits.h` header but I couldn't find any mention of it. Is it a fixed value or there a way to find out what is the maximum on my system ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick summary: Convert the pointer to `uintptr_t` (defined in `<stdint.h>`), which will give you a number in the range `0` to `UINTPTR_MAX`. Read on for the gory details and some unlikely problems you might theoretically run into.

In general there is no such thing as a "maximum value" for a pointer. Pointers are not numbers, and `<` and `>` comparisons aren't even defined unless both pointers point into the same (array) object or just past the end of it.

But I think that the *size* of a pointer is really what you're looking for. And if you can convert a `void*` pointer value to an unsigned 32-bit or 64-bit integer, the maximum value of that integer is going to be 2<sup>32</sup>-1 or 2<sup>64</sup>-1, respectively.

The type `uintptr_t`, declared in `<stdint.h>`, is an unsigned integer type such that converting a `void*` value to `uintptr_t` and back again yields a value that compares equal to the original pointer.  In short, the conversion `(uintptr_t)ptr` will not lose information.

`<stdint.h>` defines a macro `UINTPTR_MAX`, which is the maximum value of type `uintptr_t`. That's not exactly the "maximum value of a pointer", but it's probably what you're looking for.

(On many systems, including Mac OSX, pointers are represented as if they were integers that can be used as indices into a linear monolithic address space. That's a common memory model, but it's not actually required by the C standard. For example, some systems may represent a pointer as a combination of a descriptor and an offset, which makes comparisons between arbitrary pointer values difficult or even impossible.)

The `<stdint.h>` header and the `uintptr_t` type were added to the C language by the 1999 standard. For MacOS, you shouldn't have to worry about pre-C99 compilers.

Note also that the `uintptr_t` type is optional. If pointers are bigger than *any* available integer type, then the implementation won't define `uintptr_t`. Again, you shouldn't have to worry about that for MacOS. If you want to be fanatical about portable code, then you can use

```
#include <stdint.h>
#ifdef UINTPTR_MAX
/* uintptr_t exists */
#else
/* uintptr_t doesn't exist; do something else */
#endif
```

where "something else" is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for such a verbose explanation ! I think I'll go with the unsigned long for the time being (as it's the same as my system for the time being). Maybe I'll change later to use the portable style :)

Comment: @achedeuzot: I strongly suggest using `uintptr_t` instead. On your system, it's the same type, and will behave exactly the same way. On other systems, `unsigned long` might not work, but `uintptr_t` always will (if it exists, and if it doesn't you've got other problems anyway).

Comment: Yes, that's what I actually meant. I'll use `uintptr_t` but it's good to know what is "behind the screen" ;)

Answer (score 3):

You probably are looking for the value of `UINTPTR_MAX` defined in `<stdint.h>`.

As ouah's answer says, `uintptr_t` sounds like the type you really want.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me to the header file I was searching ! The type is defined as the following on my system (if anyone else comes accross this question): `typedef unsigned long   uintptr_t;`

Answer (score 2):

`unsigned long` is not guaranteed to to be able to represent a pointer value. Use `uintptr_t` which is an unsigned integer type that can hold a pointer value.

Comment: Thanks to Prashant's answer, I went to the right header file. On my system uintptr_t is defined as such: `typedef unsigned long   uintptr_t;`